# delay in VHDL register

Tags: vhdl

I have simple register which stores value as `std_logic_vector`. In simulation behavior, the output is delayed by 1 cycle. What is the reason behind that? Is it behavior due to clock'event? How to solve this issue?

Here is the code:

```
entity fault_reg is
port (
  clk       : in  std_logic;
  rst       : in  std_logic;
  reg_in    : in  std_logic_vector(NUM_PORTS - 1 downto 0);
  reg_out   : out std_logic_vector(NUM_PORTS - 1 downto 0));
end fault_reg;

architecture Behavioral of fault_reg is
begin
reg_impl : process(clk, rst)
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
          reg_out <= (others => '0');
        elsif clk'event and clk='1' then
              reg_out <= reg_in;
        end if;
    end process reg_impl;
end Behavioral;
```

Here is the waveform:
[image]

Comment: This is exactly the same question as this one which was posted only a little bit before it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496660/strange-delay-of-one-cycle-in-modules-in-verilog.  You might get more useful information looking at this one too.

Comment: so is it due to some kind of Delta delays in VHDL that there will be some delay between assigning input values to output, and as this process is synchronous, so it is writing values in the next clock cycle, right?

Comment: yes, the delay is caused by the clock.  It's known as Propagation Delay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process you written is a *synchronous process,* which is sensitive to the `clk` and `rst` signals; the process only "wakes up" to evaluate/update outputs when `clk` or `rst` changes. So even though `reg_in` may change, `reg_out` will only update on the next rising clock edge (`clk'event and clk='1'`) or reset is asserted (`rst = '1'`).

The timeline breaks down like this:

1. Rising clock edge.
2. `reg_in` changes soon after event #1.
3. Rising clock edge.
4. `reg_out` changes soon after event #3, with the value of `reg_in` that was present at event #3, which was the value that it changed to in event #2.